# Prove or disprove if its isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

$(Q^+,*)$ is isomorphic to its subgroup, consisting of rationals $\frac p q$ where $p$ and $q$ are **odd** integers.

I don't know about the cardinality of an infinite set. If two groups are isomorphic then they have the same cardinality. So how do I define a one-to-one map between these two groups? My assumption is that isomorphism between these two groups do exist, Since I couldn't find any counter-example. Please explain in detail since I am new to the group theory.

Comment: It is extremely arguable (in the sense that I would be inclined to argue that it is impossible) whether falsifying a statement in the form $[\exists x, \cdots]$ by finding a counterexample is possible. One would say that only statements in the form $[\forall x,\cdots]$ can be falsified by exhibiting a counterexample, and therefore your inability to find a counterexample to existence of an isomorphism is qualitatively inconsequential.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Let $2=p_1,p_2,p_3,\dots$ be the list of primes, and extend the mapping $p_n\mapsto p_{n+1}$.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by extending the mapping. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Extend it to be a group homomorphism, i.e. it needs to respect the multiplication operation. For an arbitrary positive rational $a/b$, consider the prime factorization of both $a$ and $b$.